# Why does my keras model require a 3D list to predict?

Tags: python, keras

I've read a few answers on here saying that models require a 2D array to predict, even though we may just want one prediction. However, for as long as I can remember my models require 3D arrays to predict on. My input shape is 2D (shape 47145, 120), though when predicting I need to place my array inside two other lists in order for it to work correctly. Output shape is a 1D array.

```
model.predict([[1, 2, 3...]])[0]
```

doesn't work, but

```
model.predict([[[1, 2, 3...]]])[0][0]
```

does. I don't mind it, and it predicts perfectly fine for me, but having to add an extra `[0][0]` after each line of prediction has led me to question if this is the expected behavior.

Here's the error message I get when I try to predict on a 2D array:

```
In [154] a = [0] * 120

In [155]: model.predict([a])
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (120,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Here is the code I use to create my model:

```
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.00055, decay=1e-6)

layer_num = 5
nodes = 80

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(x_train.shape[1], activation="relu", input_shape=(x_train.shape[1:])))
for i in range(layer_num):
    model.add(Dense(nodes, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="logs\{}-layers-{}-nodes-{}-opt-adam-decay2".format(
                          layer_num, nodes, 'relu'), histogram_freq=0, write_graph=True)
callbacks = [tensorboard]

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=opt, metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, shuffle=True, batch_size=64, validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
                                                         callbacks=callbacks, epochs=80)
```

My shapes:

```
In [146]: x_train.shape
Out[146]: (47145, 120)

In [147]: y_train.shape
Out[147]: (47145,)

In [148]: x_train[0]
Out[148]: 
array([0.51050081, 0.48233333, 0.12769333, 0.12920803, 0.13162067,
       0.12359916, 0.51050081, 0.488     , 0.12325733, 0.14299455,
       0.13225505, 0.12455976, 0.51050081, 0.49366667, 0.12325733,
       0.14299455, 0.13225505, 0.12455976, 0.51050081, 0.499     ,
       0.13022811, 0.13016997, 0.13352359, 0.12584059, 0.51050081,
       0.49566667, 0.12896078, 0.11991025, 0.13225505, 0.13096383,
       0.51050081, 0.49233333, 0.12769333, 0.11638345, 0.12940056,
       0.13032347, 0.51050081, 0.48933333, 0.12325733, 0.12407822,
       0.12718045, 0.12808203, 0.51050081, 0.49266667, 0.12547533,
       0.12696372, 0.12718045, 0.12231832, 0.51050081, 0.48933333,
       0.12547533, 0.12696372, 0.12718045, 0.12231832, 0.51050081,
       0.486     , 0.12737644, 0.12568135, 0.12654618, 0.12231832,
       0.51050081, 0.48266667, 0.12769333, 0.12119272, 0.12496034,
       0.12584059, 0.51050081, 0.47933333, 0.13181244, 0.12151326,
       0.12718045, 0.12936276, 0.51050081, 0.476     , 0.12896078,
       0.12696372, 0.1284491 , 0.12391928, 0.51050081, 0.47266667,
       0.12896078, 0.12696372, 0.1284491 , 0.12391928, 0.51050081,
       0.46933333, 0.126109  , 0.12728437, 0.12654618, 0.11783545,
       0.51050081, 0.466     , 0.12547533, 0.12343704, 0.12305742,
       0.11143137, 0.51050081, 0.46266667, 0.13022811, 0.11926895,
       0.11988585, 0.11879605, 0.51050081, 0.45933333, 0.12737644,
       0.12407822, 0.12147158, 0.12968299, 0.51050081, 0.456     ,
       0.126109  , 0.12568135, 0.12718045, 0.14761449, 0.51050081,
       0.45266667, 0.126109  , 0.12568135, 0.12718045, 0.14761449])
```

Comment: Added! So it shouldn't take a 3D array to predict?

Comment: It seems each data point is a 2-D array. I think you have set your input data as 2 dimensional. What is the length of `x_train` in your code?

Comment: @YanYang Just added more details. The shape of the first x_train element is a 1D array, with 120 elements so I don't know why it always asks for a 3D array while predicting

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is, but sometimes nd-arrays represented using packages like `numpy` are treated as (n+1) dimensional, with the first dimension having two elements: 1. the actual nd-array and 2. its type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not expected behavior; the problem arises from passing in a *list*, not an array - where behind the scenes, the former's handled as an iterable (`len([[[1,2,3]]][0].shape)==2)`), but a Numpy array is processed directly. Try `model.predict(np.array([[1,2,3,...]]))`

To your edit, `a = [0] * 120` is *not* a 2D array, but still a list - even as `[a]`.

Comment: Yep, that worked! Makes sense as the input for training is a numpy array, and my predictions were just lists, or 1 dimension less than what I trained with according to @Yan